# bad URI error from twilio api

Tags: rubygems, twilio, twilio-api

I am getting the following error when I try to use the twilio-api to send a message.

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:146:in `split': bad URI(absolute but no path): api.twilio.com:// (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

and the full stack trace:

```
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.13.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:453:in `proxy_from_env'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.13.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:85:in `initialize'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.13.1/lib/faraday.rb:67:in `new'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faraday-0.13.1/lib/faraday.rb:67:in `new'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/http/http_client.rb:21:in `_request'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/http/http_client.rb:54:in `request'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/client.rb:70:in `request'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/framework/domain.rb:20:in `request'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/framework/version.rb:51:in `request'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/framework/version.rb:154:in `create'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/twilio-ruby-5.3.1/lib/twilio-ruby/rest/api/v2010/account/message.rb:71:in `create'
from send_message.rb:19:in `mms'
```

send_message.rb

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN
client.messages.create(
  from: TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
  to: MY_PHONE_NUMBER,
  body: 'test'
)
```

If I inspect `client` I can see that it is a Twilio::Rest::Client. Could it be a gem dependency issue?

Comment: That's really weird. It looks like the domain is being set as the scheme. Are you setting the API URL somewhere else in your code? Or using a proxy?

Comment: No code changes. It must have something to do with my computer setup with ruby or gems because when I pulled the repo onto another computer, it ran successfully.

Comment: That is really odd! Glad it is working for you now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved shutting down the terminal completely, then re-starting and re-installing all the gems.